# Stabilizing and colouring poor quality wood

Tags: wood, spalted

I am thinking of getting some Stick Fast resin for stabilizing poor quality woods like spalted beech and buckeye burl. What sort of things can you add to the resin to stain/dye the wood that won't cause a chemical reaction ? Stick Fast do make colorants but expensive and limited colours.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you will need a vacuum stabilization system(about $325 new) and a quart of stabilizer (about $34) it seems that $10 for a jar of dye is not out of range.

However, to get colours beyond the primary colours offered by Stick Fast you would need to buy three jars (red, yellow blue) and mix any color you want.  Relying on basic colour theory (red and blue make purple; blue and yellow make green; etc) you can, with patience, mix any colour you want.

Comment: Stabilizing...? Chamber? If the OP is only intending to do small bits they can make up something based on a mason jar or similar, total cost I think ends up being about 30 bucks. Also, not really critical but the primary colours in printing (CMY) are the genuine primaries, not red, blue and yellow.

Comment: Graphics: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_color -- there isn't only one set.

Comment: There has been past mention here of using an almost-toy vacuum pump to perfuse wood with stabilizer; websearch will find articles about cheap rigs for the purpose. Whether Stick Fast would do the job, deponent saith not. Pigments, both dry and wet, can certainly be added to epoxy (I've seen that used for infill/inlay of several sorts); I'd say it would be worth experimenting here but I'd be surprised if anyone has much prior experience with this specific proposal.

Comment: I already have a vacuum pump for veneer work so just need a chamber, pressure pots in the UK are very dear and as i am a hobby woodworker on a limited budget so will try homemade first. I wasn't sure if any old pigment would block the pores, i already colour my epoxy resin but the colour is not critical on what im making just adds depth.

Comment: @keshlam There is only one set as we're talking about subtractive primaries — always CMY, based on trichromatic colour theory. The working sets of 'primaries' for different processes are only to deal with practical limitations of the pigments and dyes we have. But the main thing is not red, blue and yellow.

Comment: John, this process already 'blocks' the pores in the wood, with the stabilizer :-) To colour the resin though you ideally want to use dyes, not pigments as otherwise you'll tend to obscure the wood grain to some degree (same basic principle as with dye-based wood stain and pigmented wood stain).

Comment: @Graphus the products from Stick Fast say that the vacuum stabilization system is necessary in order to use the stabilizing material.  The colouring that they supply is in the form of dye.  Printing primaries - CMYK, electronic display primaries - RGB, basic introductory theory - RYB, which are the colours available from by Stick Fast.

Comment: @Graphus I see nothing in the original question that says anything about small parts.  I am thinking more like bowl blanks consisting of spalted wood.